# Read N chars or press enter to exit

Tags: bash, shell, exit

I have the following function and I want when I press enter once to run the first case and then exit. Now I have to press enter 4 times to exit. Also, want when I press only one or two numbers and then enter to show the message "Number out of Range" immediately and not after two or three times per case.

```
function MakeSomething () {
    while true; do
        echo -en "Input : "
        read -N4 vn
        echo
        case $vn in
            "") if [ -z "$vn" ] ; then vn=3000 ; echo ${vn} ; exit ; fi ; break ;;
             *) [[ $vn =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo -e '\nSorry input a number between 0011 and 2559\n' ; continue; } 
             if ((vn >= 0011 && vn <= 2559)); then echo ${vn} ; else echo -e '\nNumber out of Range, input a number between 0011 and 2559\n' ; fi ; MakeSomething ;break
        esac
    done
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me answer your problem:

> press the enter 4 times to exit.

This is because you're using `read -N4`, which means you read four characters from the input. So you need four Enter. My suggestion is to change to `-a`, read from input until `Enter` fix this.

> I press only one or two numbers and then enter to show the message "Number out 
>   of Range" immediately and not after two or three times per case.

I think you shouldn't call the function inside the `case` clause because you already using a while loop. Should just let it continue.

Here is my code: // it works

```sh
#!/bin/sh

function MakeSomething () {
while true; do
echo -en "Input : "
read -a vn
echo
case $vn in
    "") if [ -z "$vn" ] ; then vn=3000 ; echo ${vn} ; exit ; fi ; break ;;
     *) [[ $vn =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo -e '\nSorry input a number between 0011 and 2559\n' ; continue; }
# check input len
          if [ ${#vn} -ge 5 ] || [ ${#vn} -le 3 ]; then echo '\n need exactly four number'; continue; fi 
     if ((vn >= 0011 && vn <= 2559)); then echo ${vn} ; else echo -e '\nNumber out of Range, input a number between 0011 and 2559\n' ; fi
esac
done
}

MakeSomething
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but my problem is that I need to use the read -N4 parameter because I have to input 4 numbers and not less or more, and then is where my problems begin. All that I want is to input 4 numbers but when I press only enter to exit instantly.

Comment: yes, I understand your problem, you can always read all parameters in a line, and check its size, if more than four, throw an error

Comment: @swa056, I add a line in the code, maybe this can help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. That check input len line did the work.It's working perfectly now.

Comment: glad I can help. Could you please accept my answer, Thanks